# iPhone app testing and debugging from windows

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning

I have got the provisioning profiles and .app files to load the app into iPhone and test it. I am using windows machine so i am accessing xcode from a remote mac machine to see the full source code. After editing the code or after making some changes in the code in mac m/c, how can i build and load it in my device and test the app with the latest changes made in the code?

Answer (score 1):

make a build in your remote mac using the provisioning profile and send it to yourself. Then install via iTunes. Have a look at this link:

http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution

Comment: Hi, after building in the remote mac, how to archive the code or create an .app file and send it to my windows machine?

Comment: When you build, .app file is automatically created. What xcode version are you using?

Comment: I am using xcode version 4.0.2. Where can i find the .app file?

Comment: /Users/<youruseraccountname>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-<somerandomsequenceofcharacters>/Build/Products/<buildschemename>-iphoneos

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, i was able to find .app file and test it. Can you suggest me how to redirect the log messages of the running app that are written in console to DCIM folder so that when i connect my iphone to windows m/c, by default it opens only photos and videos, and after redirecting, will i be able to view logs of the app?

Comment: i dont think that is possible. Since I answered your original question please consider accepting this answer as correct